# ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup not working in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to use ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup in my ionic project for mobile.
when the user will click an icon and keep it pressed ng-mousedown should change the icon with another and on  ng-mouseup it should take user to next page.
Everything is working fine in browser but not in Mobile phone (iPhone 6).

Comment: How will you detect Mouse events on Mobile ? Everything here is a touch event.

Comment: Ionic has its own events as Javierif pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of the following links will help you:
ngTouch: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch, a better alternative for ngClick
ngTouchstart: https://github.com/nglar/ngTouchstart, instead of mousedown
ngTouchend: https://github.com/nglar/ngTouchend, instead of mouseup

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for mobile as well as desktop.Please let me know.

```
$('body').bind( "touchstart mouseup", function(e){
        $('div#extras').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});

$('body').bind( "touchend mousedown", function(e){
        $('div#extras').delay(2000).fadeTo(1500, 0);
});
```